# Teams message extension searchTerm value cut if search term starts with upper case letter

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams message extension with search commands. When I start the extenstion inside the message input using the "@appname" and execute the search command with a search term that starts with upper case letter like 'Livia', I receive only 'Liv' inside the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync method's MessagingExtensionQuery property as searchTerm. If I search using lower case letter only like 'livia', it works correctly and I receive 'livia' as searchTerm. If I add a space to the search term then it is correct also, so like in case of 'Liv ia' the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync method's MessagingExtensionQuery searchTerm value is 'Liv ia'. Same result if I test it with my name 'Gyula', I receive only 'Gy' inside OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync method.

If we start the message extenstion command using the icon bar below the message input, then it works correctly.

We are using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure 4.7.0 with .Net Core 2.1.
Do you have any idea what can cause this issue?

[Search with upper case first letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3xU8.png)
[Search with lower case first letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frNkd.png)

I can reproduce the issue using the https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search sample:
[Search term in Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIlzx.png)
[Search term received in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c5vZ.png)

This is a copy of the manifest package i used to reproduce the issue, maybe that has something?
[Teams manifest zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/stbc9y47i8597h5/TeamsAppManifestSample.zip?dl=0)

Comment: It should not be happen, Please share piece of code what you are trying so we can check it at our end. By seeing screenshot it seems you are splitting the searchText.Could you please take a look at [search based message extension](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search)?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I could reproduce the issue using that sample. I modified the text above, added the manifest, maybe that is causing the issue, but I doubt that. Also added screenshot when I search in Teams and what I get in code.

Comment: This is not a issue, We tested this and found it is by design. handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery take the search text as you start typing.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT But shouldn't it resend the search text when a user finishes typing? Why is it then working correctly when I start the search text with lowercase letter? The problem is that we never receive the full search text, so if you type 'Livia', we only receive 'Liv' and never receive 'Livia'.
When I start the search by opening the message extension using its icon below the text input and execute the search from there then it is working correctly. If it is by design, it shouldn't work there too. Based on this this shouldn't be a by design thing.